# Strange Heroku float bit-precision error (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, floating-point, floating-point-precision

Originally a coordinate field on my model was using integer, but when I tried to deploy to Heroku, I was reminded (by a crash) that I needed it to be a float instead (since I had decimal points in my coordinate). So I generated a change_column migration on my local machine, to change_column them to be floats instead. and everything went fine.

I tried to deploy to heroku again, first with a `heroku pg:reset` and then with a `heroku db:setup`. During the db:setup, I get the following error:

`PGError: ERROR:  precision for type float must be less than 54 bits
: CREATE TABLE "landmarks" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying(255), "xcoord" float(255), "ycoord" float(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)`

So I generated another change_column migration, this time with :precision option as well (set to `:precision => 50`, which is less than 54). I went through the whole deploy process again, and it gave me the same error.

Am I doing something wrong? I've deployed another app to Heroku before that used float without any modification...

I'm using SQLite on my local machine, and I think Heroku uses Postgres?

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT: I should also mention that the output SQL the error displayed after I changed the `:precision` value for my coords still said 'float(255)'...not sure why]

Comment: What did your "int to float" migration look like?

Comment: Second that. If you're still getting 'float(255)' in your CREATE TABLE statement, it's still trying to create a 255-bit floating point number. Maybe a `rake db:rollback` followed by a `rake db:migrate` with the new migration? Barring that, I'd make sure the migration file looks right and run a `rake db:reset`.

Comment: hmm...well my migration path probably looks like a monster now, since I tried changing it to float, then back to int, then to string, then to float, then to a different float, etc...is there any way for me to remove some migrations and start a new migration? The idea that my previous migrations are interfering does make sense though, I'll see what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use float(255) as the column type. Use either `real` or `double precision`. Please read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

Also we **strongly** recommend using postgres locally for development. It is all too common to run into inconsistencies—such as this—when drastically switching important parts of your stack between development and production. And your database is an important part of your stack.

Comment: Thanks Will, that did the trick! I'll keep that in mind for future dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think Postgres is complaining about the difference between bits and digits - something that has 50 digits of precision has far more than 50 bits. Put another way, 2^53 = 9,007,199,254,740,992, or 16 significant digits of accuracy. Try setting it to `:scale => 12, :precision => 15` - that should get you three digits before the decimal point, and 12 digits after, and I *believe* that puts you under the 53-bit limit.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work...still got the same error =/ tried it with smaller values too, scale => 8 and precision => 10.