# how to fix precision 0 in rails while migrating in heroku...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have been trying to push my project in heroku. i succeed to push it in heroku but when i try to do **heroku run rake db:migrate** i am geeting error to set precision to 0.

[the error i am having while migrating to heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSoMc.png)

Comment: I am not a domain expert, but should driver licence number be a string?

Comment: Please post the exact error log rather than screenshots

Comment: this is the error i am getting while migrating the database to heroku...

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a database other than PostGres for development, and PostGres for Deployment? Do you have float type columns? If yes, you might want to change them to real or double precision, per this post:
[Strange Heroku float bit-precision error (ruby on rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014368/strange-heroku-float-bit-precision-error-ruby-on-rails)